# AWK, Applescript, String/Int Parsing

Tags: parsing, awk, applescript, text-parsing, string-parsing

This is a bit in depth, and I'm in a bit over my head.  I've never used AWK, and the more I try to learn about it (perhaps it's the lateness of the hour) the more frustrating it's getting to be.

I'm trying to write an applescript... script to resize windows across my monitors.  Now, I COULD take the easy route and hardcode my monitor dimensions into the script, but instead I decided to try and gather them dynamically.  I've managed to find a code snippet that parses a plist and spits out ALMOST-useable info, here's the applescript:

```
set screenInfo to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver | awk '
        BEGIN { FS=\"= \" }
        /Active/  { screens++ }
        { gsub(\";\",\"\",$2) }
        /^ *OriginX/ { ox[screens] = $2 }
        /^ *OriginY/ { oy[screens] = $2 }
        /^ *Width/   { w[screens]  = $2 }
        /^ *Height/  { h[screens]  = $2 }
        END       {
                for (si=1;si<=screens;si++) {
                    print ox[si],oy[si],w[si],h[si]
                    }
            }'"
    return screenInfo
end getScreenInfo
```

That's working pretty well - in my "result" window, I get the following:

```
"0 0 1920 1080  
\"-1600\" 0 1600 1200  
1920 0 1680 1050  
0 0 1920 1080  
\"-1600\" 0 1600 1200  
1920 0 1680 1050  
3600 1050 1024 768  "
```

The first number pair is the coordinates for the top left corner of the monitor, the second number pair is the resolution of that monitor.  Such is the case for each monitor - though there are duplicates of monitors 1-3, plus a ghost monitor.  I don't really care about that, it should be parse-able.

My problem comes when I try to parse those numbers as ints so I can use them - using something like `set theVar to word 1 of paragraph 2 of theString as integer`, it parses as `1600`, not the `-1600` it needs to be.  I tried stepping through the entire string, 1 character at a time, to remove the escaping backslashes, but I think those only actually show up in the results window - when I `display dialog`, they don't show.  Even when I don't try to parse it as an integer, just `word 1 of paragraph 2` it ignores the `-` and returns `"1600"`.  How else can I parse this?  Goodness, I'm not a fan of applescript right now.

Comment: awk seems to be doing what you tell it. You'd need to include how you are "parse those numbers as ints", as that seems to be the trouble spot. AND I don't see why you're keeping the escaped dbl-quotes, why no just `-1600 0 1600 1200 ....` (And I don't know anything about applescript, so that could be a problem ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: I do believe applescript is the problem, but I'm not familiar enough with AWK to try and modify what it's spitting out to make it easier to parse.  Do you think you could modify the AWK to not return the double quotes?  That might do the trick.

Comment: `gsub(\";\",\"\",$2)` is replacing `";"` from the input with `\"\"` (for all matches (globably) ) in the 2nd word of the output. I think replacing with `gsub(\";\","",$2)` will work. Going to bed ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Slight syntax error in original comment. Try corrected version with `gsub(\";\","",$2)` . Hmm. a little skeptical about `(\";\",...`, doesn't seem like a true regex (awk style). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the screen resolutions with AppleScriptObjC

```
use framework "Foundation"

set screenFrames to {}
set screens to current application's NSScreen's screens()
repeat with aScreen in screens
    set end of screenFrames to aScreen's frame() as record
end repeat
```

`screenFrames` will contain a record for each screen containing records `origin` with `x` and `y` members and `size` with `width` and `height` members.

For example you can get the width of screen 1 with

```
set screen1Width to width of |size| of item 1 of screenFrames as integer
```

Comment: Nice answer! Keep them coming :-)

Comment: I certainly like the ingenuity, but this - while displaying some info - does not appear to be fully accurate; it only reports 1 screen at a time with extraneous data.